# How come the close button link doesn't work for the telerik:RadNotification control on DotNetNuke?

Tags: telerik, dotnetnuke

I'm using the telerik:RadNotification control, with `VisibleTitlebar="true"` `ShowTitleMenu="false"` and `ShowCloseButton="true"`.

When I hover over the little X (close button) the URL is **"http://localhost/mySite/href"**.  When I click on it it takes me to an `HTTP Error 404.0 - Not Found page`.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.  Is there any way to programmaticly fix the bad link?

I tried adding an `OnClientHiding="OnClientHiding"` and adding an javascript alert in the OnClientHiding method but it goes to the error page first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem was that I was not getting into the OnClientHiding event handler. It looks like some code in the OnClientShown event handler was causing this issue.